# Sending data between ajax call and .then()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
this.getData().then(this.setData());

p.getData = function(){

    return $.ajax({
        url: '/gateway/get-looks',
        type: 'POST'
    });
};

p.setData = function(data){

    console.log(data); //undefined
};
```

I'm trying to get data from an ajax call and once complete, use it's promise to perform an action on the data, unfortunately the data is `undefined` in `p.setData` - why?

Comment: try done instead of then.

Comment: Still undefined with .done()

Comment: You're calling it immediately - that's what the `()` after `this.setData` does - with no arguments, so of course `data` is going to be undefined. Try passing the reference to the function instead: `.then(this.setData);`. You may still run in to issues depending on what exactly `setData` does, especially if you need `this` to refer to something specific inside that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`$when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to return the promise.

```
this.getData().then(this.setData); 

p.getData = function(){

    return $.when($.ajax({
        url: '/gateway/get-looks',
        type: 'POST'
    }));
};

p.setData = function(data){
    console.log(data); 
};
```

**Note:** Don't use `.then(this.setData());` this will execute `setData()`, **this is why you get `undefined`** and also means that you pass the result of `setData()` as parameter to `then`.

Pass the function as parameter `.then(this.setData);` and will be executed in `then` when is called.